# Is it possible to create an Apache Beam (in python) IO connector for RabbitMQ

Tags: python, rabbitmq, apache-beam

According `Beam` documentation

https://beam.apache.org/documentation/io/developing-io-overview/

is possible to create new connectors.

I need a Messaging connector for RabbitMQ like the one is available for Java.

https://beam.apache.org/documentation/io/built-in/

So far in the guide, I don't see a way to achieve that for unbounded sources and sinks

https://beam.apache.org/documentation/io/developing-io-python/

Answer (score -1):

I also want to do something similar, any solutions or workarounds that you were able to use.

One approach I have is to

1. Start the consumer in a `DoFn`, read and stop consuming.
2. convert the output to PCollection.
3. build the rest of the pipeline.

Comment: This is not an answer.